# How Can I test Servlets with JUnit?

Tags: testing, servlets, junit

I saw Jetty has got and ServletTest class which you can use to test Servlets.

```
tester = new ServletTester();
tester.setContextPath("/");
tester.addServlet(TestServlet.class, "/servlet/*");
... 
tester.start();
```

Do you know if there is something similar in Tomcat?
How could I test a servlet?

Comment: For unit testing, it should not matter what servlet container you use. This is similar to using HSQL instead of Oracle for unit testing of database access code. So even if you write for a Tomcat deployment, if Jetty is more suitable for unit testing (faster to start, easier to configure etc),  you can go with Jetty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HttpUnit has a has a "simulated container" called [ServletUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/servletunit-intro.html).

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Jakarta Cactus](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/)

> Cactus is a simple test framework for unit testing server-side java code (Servlets, EJBs, Tag Libs, Filters, ...).

[Here's a servlet test how-to](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/writing/howto_testcase_servlet.html)

Comment: FYI Jakarta Cactus has been deprecated since 2011/08/05. :(

Answer (score 2):

I've never found a benefit to testing servlets directly (nor Struts actions, say), especially given the work needed to do it.

Most of my servlets/actions/whatever use POJOs for the bulk of their work, and the POJOs are heavily tested.  The webapps themselves have suites of HtmlUnit tests.  Everything in between I assume to be just plumbing.

I don't believe that I've even once encountered any sort of bug that would have ONLY been caught by testing the servlet classes directly, and which would not be caught by the POJO or webapp tests.

Comment: Point taken. However in my case, I've inherited a junk servlet that is terribly complex and buggy. Being able to call it from a unit test for the specific scenario that is failing will greatly shorten my debugging process. :)